# jquery.mobile 1.4.5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created a sample index.html file and included the latest jquery (3.1.0) and jquery mobile (1.4.5).

On the loading page the error console outputed:

> jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:3337 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined`

on this line:

```
mouseEventProps = $.event.props.concat( mouseHookProps ),
```

When I tried include jquery-1.11.2 there was no issue. Can any one tell me why?

Comment: Check if `jquery3` is compatible with `jquery.mobile1.4.5`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[Look this Documentation](http://blog.jquerymobile.com/2013/02/20/jquery-mobile-1-3-0-released/)

jQuery mobile is locked to some versions of jQuery! You will find a text of

> jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 supports versions of jQuery core 1.7.2 – 1.9.1 and
>   we’re actively testing the upcoming 2.0 version too. We will be
>   keeping in sync with their releases to let you take full advantage of
>   the new goodness.

**UPDATE**

jQuery mobile now works with 2.x versions too, though version 3 still returns the mentioned error.

Comment: Using the [jQuery Migrate plugin](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js) solves this nicely.

Comment: How do you make this do the job?

Comment: @dsghi I loaded the jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js on my website, but it didn't solve the problem. The error is still there. And I made sure to load the jquery-migrate file above the jquery-mobile JS file.

Comment: I apologize, I can't remember what steps I took - lesson learned, I will not post comments without usage in the future. :/

Comment: 2.1.1 worked for me, thanks :)

Just not sure why they would put jquery 3 and jquery-mobile 1.4.5 on the same download page, my mind automatically figured "yah, they must be related"

Comment: using jquery migrate plugin really helped me to solve the issue

Answer (score 32):

Use latest version **1.5**
 ( It is available at:
 [code.jquery.com](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/)):

```
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.js
```

Comment: this answer work from me. I use 1.5.0-alpha instead of 1.4.5

Comment: Coloquei esta versão 1.5 e resolveu meu problema. 
I put this version 1.5 and solved my problem.

Comment: rip jQuery mobile 2019, thumbs up pls !!

Comment: 1.5 is now out of Alpha and is now a Release Candidate 1: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.js

Comment: Thanks! This removed this particular issue. But then ran into the next one: Can not read property 'defaults' of undefined.. on this code..  $.mobile.changePage.defaults   Any suggestion?