# Locally hosted Jquery.js not working, CDN link works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

My HTML references

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

 <script src="js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

 <script src="js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

 <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/index.css'/>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Referencing `<script src="js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` simply doesnt work and throws an `Uncaught TypeError` But `"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js` Works.

I know my local path is correct, because if i were to use the JQuery CDN, `<script src="js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>` Will work fine.

My folder structure:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Im confused as to why I can use the JQuery Mobile library locally hosted, but not the JQuery libary. 
Probably an obvious answer but its flying right above my head!

EDIT- The Call Stack

```
165.9 ms68.49 % 165.9 ms68.49 % (program)   
29.5 ms12.18 %  44.8 ms18.49 %  (anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:13   
13.2 ms5.46 %   25.4 ms10.50 %  (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2   
3.1 ms1.26 %    12.2 ms5.04 %   (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2   
2.0 ms0.84 %    46.8 ms19.33 %  (anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:1    
2.0 ms0.84 %    2.0 ms0.84 %    bjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3  
2.0 ms0.84 %    4.1 ms1.68 %    eachjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2   
2.0 ms0.84 %    4.1 ms1.68 %    (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2   
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    (garbage collector) 
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)extensions::SafeBuiltins:1  
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)extensions::SafeBuiltins:1  
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    htmlPrefilterjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3  
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    readyjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2  
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    r.Eventjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3    
1.0 ms0.42 %    5.1 ms2.10 %    (anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:1993 
1.0 ms0.42 %    2.0 ms0.84 %    (anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:1408 
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:1264 
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    appendChild 
1.0 ms0.42 %    3.1 ms1.26 %    stylejquery-3.1.1.min.js:3  
1.0 ms0.42 %    2.0 ms0.84 %    r.parseHTMLjquery-3.1.1.min.js:4    
1.0 ms0.42 %    26.5 ms10.92 %  (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:1   
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    Ujquery-3.1.1.min.js:3  
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    Deferredjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2   
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    cachejquery-3.1.1.min.js:3  
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    makeArrayjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2  
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    Iajquery-3.1.1.min.js:3 
1.0 ms0.42 %    2.0 ms0.84 %    hjquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:2066    
1.0 ms0.42 %    2.0 ms0.84 %    jajquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    a.widgetjquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:765  
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4   
1.0 ms0.42 %    1.0 ms0.42 %    createHTMLDocument  
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    triggerHandlerjquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 
0 ms0 % 3.1 ms1.26 %    r.fn.(anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4  
0 ms0 % 3.1 ms1.26 %    rjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2  
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    Rjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2  
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    bindjquery-3.1.1.min.js:4   
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    Jajquery-3.1.1.min.js:3 
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    prependjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3    
0 ms0 % 3.1 ms1.26 %    r.fn.initjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2  
0 ms0 % 4.1 ms1.68 %    Sjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3  
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    r.fn.(anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3  
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    onjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3 
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    a.cleanDatajquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:755   
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    removejquery-3.1.1.min.js:3 
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    a.mobile.Navigatorjquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:2921   
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3   
0 ms0 % 3.1 ms1.26 %    (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4   
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4   
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2   
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    xajquery-3.1.1.min.js:3 
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    datajquery-3.1.1.min.js:3   
0 ms0 % 0 ms0 % (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3   
0 ms0 % 2.0 ms0.84 %    eachjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2   
0 ms0 % 5.1 ms2.10 %    (anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:39   
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:323  
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    triggerjquery-3.1.1.min.js:4    
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    pajquery-3.1.1.min.js:3 
0 ms0 % 0 ms0 % insertBefore    
0 ms0 % 2.0 ms0.84 %    setjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3    
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:3200 
0 ms0 % 15.3 ms6.30 %   (anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:24   
0 ms0 % 2.0 ms0.84 %    cssjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3    
0 ms0 % 2.0 ms0.84 %    Najquery-3.1.1.min.js:3 
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3   
0 ms0 % 2.0 ms0.84 %    pixelMarginRightjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3   
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    addjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3    
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    (anonymous function)extensions::SafeBuiltins:1  
0 ms0 % 1.0 ms0.42 %    getjquery-3.1.1.min.js:3    
0 ms0 % 2.0 ms0.84 %    ga.setDoc
```

The Error

```
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined(anonymous function) @ jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError`  that error to me doesn't imply it can't find jquery,. What's the rest of your call stack like?

Comment: make sure the html is in the folder projects/IDer/IDer

Comment: jQuery mobile doesn't yet support versions >2.1.x - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8381

Comment: What error are you getting in console?

Comment: @Keith I tried to add a photos of my call stack, but I cant due to not having enough rep points.

Comment: Are you sure your CDN's were using the same versions?..  As this error looks like -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497347/jquery-mobile-1-4-5-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-concat-of-undefin

Comment: @Keith I've included the call stack in { } in the OP
and I've posted the error in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some functions of `jquery.mobile-1.4.5` not be compatible with `jquery-3.1.1` .Use `jquery-2.2.4` version . You can download from here [link](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js)

Comment: Good answer, but I cannot find a download link, just CDNs.

Comment: Ohh it changes.Use this link https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: On that page just right click and click `Save Page as`

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome.You can accept this as answer.If you do'nt know you can check here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow