# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.event.props.concat')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

Run my `html` in `browser` export error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.event.props.concat')

The error in `safari`:

My code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charse=utf-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../js/lib/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>leo maer page one</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where is the mistake? I can find nothing with it.

---

** EDIT - 1 **

I have tested:`jquery：2.0.3` and
`jquery-mobile:1.4.0`,
it works fine. The `jquery.mobile-1.4.5` and `jquery-3.1.1` is the newest `version`, I think there maybe the reason.

Comment: hi, i doubt that may be your jquery js path is not correct. please check and try again

Comment: @Annshuk I promise it is the correct path, and I can `click` into the source.

Comment: someone already answer it . please read below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497347/jquery-mobile-1-4-5-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-concat-of-undefin

Comment: @Annshuk Your link is right,thank you.