# jQuery Mobile: Header not showing up

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is a bit strange. I use jQuery mobile version 1.4.5. When I use jQuery versions less than 3 header and footer do not show up. But when I use jQuery 3x they show up but I get the error:

```
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:3337 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
```

How can I work around this? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497347/jquery-mobile-1-4-5-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-concat-of-undefin

Comment: @anu It's no use. I tried it with 1.9.1 and still the same