# Has anyone had this issue with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, concatenation

Issue in JQuery Mobile

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined**

Any knowledge of how to fix the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery.mobile 1.4.5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497347/jquery-mobile-1-4-5-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-concat-of-undefin)

Answer (score 0):

issue fixed :)

wasn't compatible with my current JQuery